Error: *** Deployment Failed *** migration hit an invalid opcode
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
contract Migrations {
address public owner;
uint256 public last_completed_migration;
constructor() {
    owner = msg.sender;
}

modifier restricted() {
    if (msg.sender == owner) _;
}

function setCompleted(uint256 completed) public restricted {
    last_completed_migration = completed;
}

}
this is my Migration.sol

solc: 0.8.26+commit.8a97fa7a.Emscripten.clang
PS C:\Users\User\Documents\Pictures\verifiland-main\migrations> truffle migrate

Compiling your contracts...
✓ Fetching solc version list from solc-bin. Attempt #1

Compiling .\contracts\LandRegistrationSystem.sol
Compiling .\contracts\Migrations.sol
Artifacts written to C:\Users\User\Documents\Pictures\verifiland-main\build\contracts
Compiled successfully using:


solc: 0.8.26+commit.8a97fa7a.Emscripten.clang

Starting migrations...

Network name:    'development'
Network id:      5777
Block gas limit: 6721975 (0x6691b7)

1_initial_migration.js
Deploying 'Migrations'
*** Deployment Failed ***
"Migrations" hit an invalid opcode while deploying. Try:

Verifying that your constructor params satisfy all assert conditions.
Verifying your constructor code doesn't access an array out of bounds.
Adding reason strings to your assert statements.

Exiting: Review successful transactions manually by checking the transaction hashes above
on Etherscan.
Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***
"Migrations" hit an invalid opcode while deploying. Try:

Verifying that your constructor params satisfy all assert conditions.
Verifying your constructor code doesn't access an array out of bounds.
Adding reason strings to your assert statements.

at C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\deployer\src\deployment.js:330:1

Truffle v5.11.5 (core: 5.11.5)
Node v16.20.0
its throwing this error

not the answer. but don't use truffle, it is outdated and no longer maintained!. Hardhat is good and nicer when you get use to it
